# How can i prevent a stackoverflow exception in my software?

Tags: c#

I have an audio player that loads a configuration file with a list of files to be played at certain intervals. Like 5 files should be looped between 09:30 and 11:30 - it is an application for libraries where they need the background music.

When im outside of an interval, i loop through all my time intervals (there might be 2 hours before next interval starts) and then if i find that nothing is to be played right now - i sleep for a second and then try again.

I have a problem where i get a stack overflow after around 3-4 hours of checking for these time intervals (often at nights, because the clients are on, but no music should be playing at night).

```
private void PlayNextFile()
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    if (currentState == PlayerState.Started)
    {
        //if we find the next slide then play it
        AudioSlide slideToPlay = FindNextSlide();
        if(slideToPlay != null)
        {
            PlaySlide(slideToPlay);
        }
        else
        {
            MedianLog.Log.Instance.LogDebug("Did not find a slide to play now, will check again in a second");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            PlayNextFile();
        }               
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to get around this exception?

Comment: Dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825530/preventing-stackoverflow-in-recursive-functions

Comment: Maybe something like filling a "next file" queue and regularily processing this queue?

Comment: Create a while loop instead of recursion.

Comment: Never never never never never never call `Application.DoEvents`.  Doing so makes your code re-entrant.   The fact you are using unguarded-recursion doesn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just filling up your stack with not controlled recursive calls.

A while loop would be a better solution.
Something like that should do it correctly:

```
    private async void PlayNextFile()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (currentState == PlayerState.Started)
            {
                //if we find the next slide then play it
                AudioSlide slideToPlay = FindNextSlide();
                if (slideToPlay != null)
                {
                    PlaySlide(slideToPlay);
                    return;
                }

                MedianLog.Log.Instance.LogDebug("Did not find a slide to play now, will check again in a second");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }      
    }
```

Comment: You probably still want the log/sleep in an `else`. Otherwise, it's going to be mis-reporting events in the debug log.